# How to ask hibernate don't read the "hibernate.properties" in classpath via spring configuration

Tags: hibernate, spring, configuration

There is a "hibernate.properties" file in classpath which is shared by some tools, so I can't remove it.

But I want to create a "hibernate.test.properties" for testing, whose content is different from "hibernate.properties".

Then I configure the spring:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        proxy-target-class="true" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.test.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}" />
        <property name="url" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateProps"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">${hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">${hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idleTestPeriod">${hibernate.c3p0.idleTestPeriod}s</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statement">${hibernate.c3p0.max_statement}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">${hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">${hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProps" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.pojo" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

But I found although I specified new properties in this file, hibernate will still read the properties from "hibernate.properties" and override them. So I always get a wrong connection.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give couple of options .

1. In hibernate.test.properties, try changing the property names.
2. Inject separate property file to hibernateproperties

   ```
   <property name="hibernateProperties">
          <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.PropertiesFactoryBean">
          <property name="location" value="classpath:myHibernate.properties"/>
      </bean>
   </property>
   ```

Comment: use `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean` instead of `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.PropertiesFactoryBean` (spring 3.1.x)

Answer (score 1):

With new versions of Spring (3 or 3.1?) you can use Spring profiles:

```
<beans profile="test">
   ... your bean definitions
</beans>
<beans profile="normal">
   ... your bean definitions
</beans>
```

Then you can use Aravind A method

In the "old way" you may separate your normal and test spring contexts. It is perhaps what you have done but then how comes your normal hibernate.properties is loaded and used as a placeholder? There may be some problems in your context hierarchy because what you have done is supposed to work